# Define sets in Visio DB design

Tags: database, database-design, visio

I have `Transaction` table that contain transactions related cashiers transactions. Transactions might be two `sales` and `refund` and are defined in TransType table. Possible in future we will have more. Trying to show this in `Visio 2016`, but not sure I do it correctly.
[image]

How to define set of available record values in `TranType` and define relation to `Transactios` table. What type relation it would be?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a `TransTypeId` in your `TransType` table.

Then, in the `Transactions` table, create a column that serves as a foreign key, linking the two tables. `TransTypeFk` in your `Transactions` tables should then be an integer with a foreign key constraint to TransTypeId.

As a note, your relationship path between the two entities should always connect two specific columns, not a column and an entity.

The relationship would be one `TransType` to many `Transactions`.

You can define the set of available records by adding rows to that database. For Visio, using a note or text box would likely work fine.